# ''Reading'' polynomials at the first glance

Tags: polynomials, big-list

I'm reading Proofs from the Book, and I ran into following theorem:

Suppose all roots of polynomial $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0$ are real. Then the roots are contained in the interval:

$$ - \frac{a_{n-1}}{n} \pm \frac{n-1}{n} 
     \sqrt{a_{n-1}^2 - \frac{2n}{n-1} a_{n-2} } $$

So, if you know that all the roots of polynomial are real, you can get an interval that contains them just looking at the first two coefficients.

I'm interested in other theorems/tricks that let you figure out interesting things about a polynomial just by ''eyeing'' it. Especially if they are surprising!

Comment: [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) is cool and all if you're lucky with your coefficients. It gives you a way of spotting certain polynomials with no rational roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1x+a_0\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

$\bullet$ The [Perron Irreducibility Criterion](http://rms.unibuc.ro/bulletin/pdf/53-3/perron.pdf) states that if $a_0\neq 0$ and $|a_{n-1}|>1+|a_{n-2}| + \cdots +|a_1| + |a_0|$, then $f$ irrreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, (consequently over the rationals too, by the second [Gauss's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29)).

$\bullet$ The well-known [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) states that if there exists a prime number $p$ such that

1. $p$ divides $a_i$, for all $i\in \{1,\ldots, n-1\}$,
2. $p$ does not divide $a_n$,
3. $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$,

then $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$ and in $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Answer (score 2):

The Eneström–Kakeya theorem:

If $P(z)=a_nz^n+\cdots+a_0$ where $$0<a_0<a_1<\cdots<a_n,$$
then all the zeros of $P$ lie in the unit disc $|z|<1$ in the complex plane.

(See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188039/showing-that-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-with-descending-positive-coefficients-lie) for a proof.)