# Proving that a complex polynomial has no roots on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

> Let $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}z^{k}$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with real
>   coefficients satisfying $$a_{0}>a_{1}>....>a_{n-1}>a_{n}>0$$ Prove
>   that $p(z)=0$ implies $\left|z\right|>1$.

I have seen similar questions here but none of them proves that solutions can't exist on the unit circle.

Links for similar questions:
[Showing that the roots of a polynomial with descending positive coefficients lie in the unit disc.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188039/showing-that-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-with-descending-positive-coefficients-lie)

[Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence. Prove that the power series $\sum a_n x^n$ has no roots in $A=\{z\in C:|z|<1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609501/let-a-n-be-a-decreasing-sequence-prove-that-the-power-series-sum-a-n-xn-h?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: In the summation by parts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2609523), we have the strict inequality $$\lvert (1-z)p(z)\rvert > a_0 - \sum_{k = 1}^n (a_{k-1} - a_k)\lvert z\rvert^k - a_n \lvert z\rvert^{n+1}$$ for all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert = 1$ except for $z = 1$. And that $z = 1$ isn't a zero follows by positivity of the coefficients.

Comment: How is that inequality derived in the first place? The derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/188050/173410) seems much cleaner.

Comment: Hint: If $a,b\in\Bbb C $ and $|a|>|b|$ then $a+b\ne0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof from [Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence. Prove that the power series $\sum a_n x^n$ has no roots in $A=\{z\in C:|z|<1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609501/let-a-n-be-a-decreasing-sequence-prove-that-the-power-series-sum-a-n-xn-h/2609523#2609523) can be modified slightly to show that $|z| \le 1$ is not possible for a zero of $p$:

If $p(z) = 0$ and $|z| \le 1$ then
$$
\begin{align}
 a_0  &= \lvert a_0 - (1-z)p(z) \rvert 
 = \left\lvert  \sum_{k = 1}^{n} (a_{k-1} - a_k)z^k + a_n z^{n+1} \right\rvert \\
 &\underset{(*)}{\le} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} (a_{k-1} - a_k) |z^k| + a_n |z| ^{n+1}  \\
 &\underset{(**)}{\le} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} (a_{k-1} - a_k) + a_n  = a_0 \, .
\end{align}
$$
So equality holds

- in the triangle inequality $(*)$, which means that all complex numbers  $(a_{k-1} - a_k)z^k$ and $a_n z^z$ are zero, or have the same argument (see for example [Prove equality in triangle inequality for complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397582/prove-equality-in-triangle-inequality-for-complex-numbers)),
- and in $(**)$, which implies $|z|=1$.

The positive factors do not affect the argument, therefore $z, z^2, \ldots, z^n$ must all have the same argument. In particular, $z = z^2/z$ is real and positive, with absolute value $1$, so that $z=1$. But $p(1) \ne 0$, obviously.

Comment: I don't understand this part "which implies that the ratios of all terms $(a_{k-1} - a_k)z^k$ are real and non-negative, and that is only possible for $z=0$ or $z=1$."

Comment: In order for us to have equality in the first triangle inequality, all complex number 'vectors' $(a_{k-1} -a_k)z^k$ and $a_nz^{n+1}$ must point in the same direction. The coefficient of each $z^i$ is real and positive, and hence each of the $z^i$ itself must point in the same direction. This is only possible if $z$ is real and nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Km356: I have tried to explain it better.