# Zeros of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I am struggling with the following last part of a problem. I have reduced everything to the following lemma which I can not prove. Let

$$P(z) = a_{n} x^{n} + \cdots + a_{0}$$

a polynomial with real coefficients such that $0 \leq a_{0} \leq \cdots \leq a_{n}$. How can I prove that all the roots of $P(z)$ are contained in the circumference $|z|\leq 1$?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Are there more conditions? For example $P = x^2+x$ gives a contradiction

Comment: Sorry, It was $|z|\leq 1$.

Comment: If the coefficients are *strictly* decreasing then $|z| < 1$ holds, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3536695/42969.

Comment: I think the same proof that is written in the post can be applied to this case. Don't you think @MartinR?