# $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ with coefficient $a>b>c>d>0$. Show that the magnitude of all its roots is less than $1$.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Question:

> $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ with coefficient $a>b>c>d>0$.
> Show that the magnitude of all its roots is less than $1$.

First of all, it's easy to finish the proof if the three roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are real.
That is $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=(-\frac{b}{a})^2-2(\frac{c}{a})=\frac{b^2-2ac}{a^2}<\frac{b^2}{a^2}<\frac{a^2}{a^2}<1$.

But the case of $\alpha,\beta=\bar\alpha$ are conjugate complex numbers and $\gamma$ is real.
I have tried that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2+|\gamma|^2=2\alpha\beta+\gamma^2$
$=2\cdot(\frac{-d}{a\gamma})+\gamma^2\geq 3\sqrt[3]{(\frac{d}{a})^2}$ by AM-GM, and it doesn't work. And also
$=2\cdot(\frac{c}{a}-\gamma(\alpha+\beta))+\gamma^2$ $=2\cdot(\frac{c}{a}-\gamma\cdot(-\frac{b}{a}-\gamma))+\gamma^2$ $=3\gamma^2+\frac{2b}{a}\gamma+\frac{2c}{a}$ $\geq\cdots$ and it still cannot to be $\leq 1$. Please help, and thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: $\;f(-1) = \ldots$

Comment: $f(-1)=-a+b-c+d<0, f(0)=d>0$, thus $|\gamma|<1$

Comment: Right, that's all you need.

Comment: Really? Is that it? I don't get it, sorry~

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Did you mean the plural "*all roots*" in "*the absolute value of its root*"?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English. I need to show that both $|\alpha|<1, |\beta|<1, |\gamma|<1$

Comment: That follows from the Eneström–Kakeya theorem, see for example [Showing that the roots of a polynomial with descending positive coefficients lie in the unit disc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188039/showing-that-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-with-descending-positive-coefficients-lie).

Comment: wow, thank you very very much. I will read that article and study it.

Comment: WARNING: Your edition is wrong because for the complex numbers there are not order.

Comment: @Piquito AFAICT the inequalities have real numbers on both sides, since $\,\alpha+\beta, \alpha\beta, \gamma\,$ are all real. Anyway, those come from OP's post, I did not change any of the math in the edit I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to prove it, albeit with some more calculations, is to use The [Routh–Hurwitz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion#Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_criterion_for_second,_third_and_fourth-order_polynomials) for real cubics, which can be stated as:

> The third-order polynomial $Q(x)=A x^{3} + B x^{2} + C x + D$ has all roots in the open left half-plane if and only if $A, B, C, D$ have the same sign and $B\,C \gt A\,D\,$.

Let $\,P(x) = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d\,$ with roots $\,x_k \,\big|_{k=1,2,3}\,$. The [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) $\,x \mapsto \frac{x+1}{x-1}\,$ maps the open left half-plane to the open unit disc, so the roots of $\,P(x)\,$ lie strictly inside the unit circle iff the roots of $\,Q(x) = (x-1)^3 P\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\,$ lie in the left half-plane, and $Q(x)$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
Q(x) &= (x-1)^3 P\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)
\\ &= a(x+1)^3 + b(x+1)^2(x-1) + c(x+1)(x-1)^2 + d(x-1)^3
\\ &= \underbrace{(a + b + c + d)}_{A} x^3 + \underbrace{(3 a + b - c - 3 d)}_{B} x^2 + \underbrace{(3 a - b - c + 3 d)}_{C} x + \underbrace{a - b + c - d}_{D}
\end{align}
$$

$Q(x)\,$ satisfies the conditions of the Routh–Hurwitz criterion, since $\,A,B,C,D \gt 0\,$, and:

$$
\begin{align}
B\,C - A\,D &= (3a + b - c - 3d)(3a - b - c + 3d) - (a+b+c+d)(a - b + c - d)
\\ &= 8 \big(a(a - c) + d(b - d)\big)
\\ & \gt 0
\end{align}
$$

This means the roots of $\,Q(x)\,$ lie in the open left half-plane, and therefore the roots of $\,P(x)\,$ lie strictly inside the unit circle, so they all have magnitudes $\,\lt 1\,$.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I learn a lot of theorem that I have never heard about this kind of questions.

Answer (score 3):

After I read that article. I mimic the solution to do my special case problem.
Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$
Consider $g(x)=(1-x)f(x)$
$=(1-x)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$
$=-ax^4+(a-b)x^3+(b-c)x^2+(c-d)x+d$
Suppose $|z|>1$ be a root of $f(x)$ and hence a root of $g(x)$, thus
$az^4=(a-b)z^3+(b-c)z^2+(c-d)z+d$
$a|z|^4=|az^4|=|(a-b)z^3+(b-c)z^2+(c-d)z+d|$
$\leq (a-b)|z|^3+(b-c)|z|^2+(c-d)|z|+d$
$<(a-b)|z|^3+(b-c)|z|^3+(c-d)|z|^3+d|z|^3$
$=a|z|^3$
contradict with $|z|>1$.
So $|z|\leq 1$