# A question about roots of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enestrom-Kakeya Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185818/enestrom-kakeya-theorem)

Suppose that $0<a_0\leq a_1\leq\cdots\leq a_n$, then prove that the complex polynomial
$$P_n(z)=a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}z+a_n$$ cannot have a root in the unit disc, i.e., such that $|z|<1$.

Comment: This question was asked and answered fairly recently here but I don't have a specific link that I can point to.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188039/showing-that-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-with-descending-positive-coefficients-lie?lq=1